# How to Mint/Issue additional tokens(i.e increase the token quantity) using Tokens SDK and Accounts

Tags: corda

Assuming I have created a fungible token for an Account with name Issuer on the Corda Node with token quantity as 1000(MY_CUSTOM_TOKEN), I have transferred them to other accounts on the Corda Node and the token quantity has reduced to zero on the Issuer's Account, How to mint/issue additional tokens on the Issuers Account, I don't see any OOB class available to Issue/Mint additional token in the Token's SDK. Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to issue more tokens the similar way you issued them the first time. You just need to run the issue flow again. The OOB flow used to issue token is `IssueTokens` flow.

Take a look at this blog post for more details: https://medium.com/corda/introduction-to-token-sdk-in-corda-9b4dbcf71025